Excel stuck at 0% when opening a password-protected sheet
On the affected machine, if you try to open a password-protected Excel sheet (only modifying is password-protected), Excel hangs at the splash screen, displays the file name and "loading... 0%" and never does anything after that. Normally it should pop open a dialog box prompting for the password, and there is a "Read-only" button that you can hit, and that is what my user has been doing for years.
Office 2016 32-bit (machine is Windows 11 Pro, 64-bit)
What I've tried:

Copying and pasting the file (this fixed another Excel sheet that was behaving the same way)
Disabling all add-ins
Installed KB4484305
Making a new sheet from scratch with the modify password protection (same behavior)
Running the Office repair tool in Programs and Features/Uninstall or change a program
I've ruled out if it's a Trusted Location issue by comparing it to my machine.
I've ruled out if it's to do with Protected View or File Block settings by comparing it to my machine. (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings)
Verified that the Office version is the same as machines that do work. (16.0.4266.1001)
Uninstalled and re-installed Office.

Additional info:

The timing of when it started roughly lines up with November patch Tuesday (but the KB mentioned above did not fix it).
If you hold CTRL and double-click the .exe, Excel in Safe Mode does not launch (this and the original scenario both have dialogs popping up?). But for all of the other Office programs, this does work and the Safe Mode prompt appears.
Excel in Safe Mode does launch if you run "excel.exe /safe" from Run (there is no dialog box popup when you do it this way versus number 2)
If you have Excel already open, the password-protected sheet opens fine, the password dialog box appears, etc.
EDIT: I also have this exact same issue on another user/machine with the same timeline.

